# Java starting thread issue

Tags: java, multithreading

Here's just part of my code, if you guys would need whole code, let me know.So my issue is, that this part `if(shoot) thread.start();`actually doesn't work as I'd like it to work.Using KeyListener boolean variable shoot becomes true after pressing space key.If I use just `thread.start()` everything works fine, but I don't want to start thread on program launch, but after pressing space button(after variable shoot becomes true).Thank you for suggenstions!

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
super.paintComponent(g);

i=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jakub\\Desktop\\pm.gif");
pacman=i.getImage();

g.drawImage(pacman,x,y,this);

if(shoot){
g.drawOval(newX+20,y+10,10,10);
}

if(repaint)
    repaint();
 }

public static void main(String args[]){
Buffer z= new Buffer();
z.setBackground(Color.cyan);

frame=new JFrame();
frame.setSize(500,500);
frame.add(z);
frame.addKeyListener(z);
frame.setVisible(true);

thread=new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try{
        for (int i=0;i<=20;i++){
            newX=newX+i;
            repaint=true;
            Thread.sleep(100);                
            }
    }catch(InterruptedException v){System.out.println(v);}
    }
};
if(shoot)
    thread.start();
}
    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
    shoot=true;
}
```

Comment: Where's the implementation of your listener?

Comment: Oh, I mentioned this is just part of code, because whole code is pretty long but lemme add it there.

Comment: Where are boolean variables `shoot` and `repaint`?

Comment: Allright, let me add paintComponent method.

Comment: Tip: When you have situations like that, try to reduce the problem. Begin with verifying that you're actually listening to the key you want - put some `print` there and verify that you see the output when you hit spacebar. Then, if it works, try to put `thread.start()` **inside** the `if` - If it works, then you know what's the problem..

Comment: Posted code does not compile, there's one extra }, so I don't know how you're even having runtime bugs...

Comment: @MarounMaroun I tried to do this exactly same way, and I'm sure boolean variable changes it's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making variable true when a key is pressed, what you can do is perform the task of starting the thread within the **keyPressed()** method itself.

Answer (score 3):

```
    if(shoot)
        thread.start();
=>  }
```

After you start your application, it creates a new JFrame, sets its size etc., creates a `Thread` instance, checks if `shoot` is true, it is false thus does not start the thread. Afterwards it waits at the point provided above for JFrame to be closed. When you click `shoot`, your application is still waiting at that point so it never checks if `shoot` is true or false.

What you can do instead would be moving the code above into your key listening method. Don't forget to move `shoot` into appropriate place too.